# Unable to update leads to closed won due to custom lead source object | Required Field Missing

Tags: opportunity, custom-field, error-messages

[image]

Having an error code: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING generated when attempting to convert leads to Closed Won. This only happens at the closed-won stage, regardless of the lead source type entered. Does anybody have feedback on the steps I can take to correct this?

We have a standard lead source object, and also a custom lead source object I'm wondering if having both is interfering. We want to keep the custom lead source, but I'm not able to see a way to deactivate/hide the standard object lead source.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that a flow or process builder named `Opportunity - Auto Create Next Deal` has failed because it is doing DML on some object where custom field `Lead_Source__c` has no value.

**Diagnostic steps:**

- If this is kicked off by Lead Conversion as you assert, check the Lead Conversion field mappings to see what field on the Lead record is being mapped to Account/Contact/Opportunity `Lead_Source__c`.
- Then, ascertain why the source field for the mapping is NULL (or
  possibly, there is no mapping at all)
- If the above isn't productive, check the logic in the Flow itself or the logic in anything that the flow triggers (DML on records directly or indirectly).  This will be easiest to see via the debug log where the DML is occurring. For whatever reason, those triggered logic paths are setting `Lead_Source__c` to null on some object. You'll then need to trace down why